# Kubernetes Ingress Nginx Not Resolve Non Root Path

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I've setup the haproxy with kubernetes ingress controller https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress and everything works fine when I try to resolve the root path http://example.com, but if I try to resolve any subpath http://example.com/blue I always get not found 404. Please any idea why the sub-paths are not working? Below my haproxy config and ingress resource. Thanks.

haproxy.cfg

```
frontend http_front
  bind *:80
  stats uri /haproxy?stats
  default_backend http_back

backend http_back
  balance roundrobin
  server kube 192.168.1.10:80
```

ingress-resource.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /blue
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx-deploy-blue
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Could you describe your infrastructure in more detail ? What is the place of `haproxy` in all this ? Is it running in a separate `Pod` ? Did you try to run it without `haproxy` ? What happens if you try to reach the service represented by the `/blue` path in your `Ingress` directly ? Let's say run `kubectl proxy &` on your `master` and then `curl -v http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/nginx-deploy-blue`. Does it show `200 OK` status ?

Comment: Hi @mario thanks for your answer, I've setup my bare metal cluster using Nginx + MetalLB + Nginx ingress Controller and everything is working fine now.